# How to play m3u8 file chewie flutter?

Tags: flutter, m3u8

Currently, I'm using chewie plugin https://pub.dev/packages/chewie in a flutter to play a video file m3u8,
But I need to play the file from phone storage,

Please suggest me how to play the file from phone storage in chewie plugin

Or suggest me the best way to play m3u8 file in the flutter

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the m3u8 file online? you can try to parse it using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hls_parser

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

Based on the `chewie` package's documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie#installation), you need to add the `chewie` package and `video_player` package.

Because, as `chewie`'s creator mentioned:

> Chewie uses the `video_player` under the hood and wraps it in a friendly Material or Cupertino UI!

After that you can add your file from the storage like this:

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

// From a file
final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(/*Your file here*/); 

// From a DataSource
final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(/*Your DatSource*/);

// From network or Internet
final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(/*Your URL*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to the play the video from your storage, the best ways I can think of is:

- You fetch all the `media data` in your page, and make the data interactive enough to be played on the click
- You can use [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package, and select the item you want to play. You will get the path of the file using this package, which you can use to play the video in your `cheiwie` player

**For single file pickup**

```
File file = await FilePicker.getFile();
```

**For multiple file pickup**

```
        List<File> files = await FilePicker.getMultiFile(
          type: FileType.custom,
          allowedExtensions: ['m3u8']
        );
```

Make a button, and trigger it, and play it with `chewie`. I am assuming that you know how to use your `chewie` player, but following these would help get to make your player work:

- [Flutter Chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie)
- [Flutter Video Player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

If you are confused over making the player to work, you can follow [Hisam Answer for chewie player usage in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155985/5362583)